# Blocking AJAX Post requests on webapp hosted in Amazon ALB with WAF enabled - in case form data contains space character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-waf, amazon-alb

my application hosted in ALB and waf enabled, getting 403 on all the ajax request which is having the word "anything space on*". for example if i have a textfield with the input like "test one", when the same data is passing to the ajax data getting 403 error. when i am using stringify the same data, the error is not coming.

```
var value = "test one"; //inputFieldText
$ajax({"url":"url",data:value}) // data from input field, if having space on* failed. 

$ajax({"url":"url",data:JSON.stringify(value)}) // if same data is stringified then working fine.
```

if stringify is the only way, then i have 1000 of ajax request in my application, Any work around or suggestions ? please advice.

Comment: Surely there are some logs or diagnostics in the ALB WAF you can look at to see what's triggering this?

Comment: A 403 response means that you do not have access to the resource you're requesting. Generally this means that you need to add authentication headers to the request you send to verify who you are, and that you have the rights to get a response. Check the documentation for the endpoint you're calling

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, am using sessions for authorizing the user, i cannot add my username and password on each request. can you suggest me, what can i use in the authorization header instead of username and password.

Comment: Not really, as it's entirely dependent on how your system is set up.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply override jQuery $ajax and apply `JSON.stringify()` there:

```
const originalAjax = $.ajax;
$.ajax = (...args) => {
    // play with data before calling ajax
    return originalAjax(...args);
};
```

or you can extend the $ajax function and apply your own logic in extended version:

```
(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], function(jQuery) {
            factory(jQuery);
        });
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
})(this, function(jQuery) {

    var ajax = jQuery.ajax,
    
    function extendedAjax(options) {
        var promise  = $.Deferred();
        var success  = options.success;
        var error    = options.error;
        var complete = options.complete;
        var params, that = this;
        
        params = {
            complete: function(xhr, status) {
                if (complete) complete.apply(that, arguments);
            },
            success: function() {
                if (success) success.apply(that, arguments);
                promise.resolveWith(this, arguments);
            },
            error: function() {
                if (error) error.apply(this, arguments);
                promise.rejectWith(this, arguments);
            }
        };

        ajax(jQuery.extend({}, options, params));

        return promise;
    };
    
    jQuery.ajax = function(options) {
        return extendedAjax(options);
    };

});
```

this will help implement any custom logic once and for all.